# Pymongo fails to reconnect

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I've got 3 instances of mongodb running, all with `"priority" : 1`.
I run a gunicorn app with pymongo and once in a while (maybe once a month, works fine most of the time) it fails to find the primary node with `ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No primary available for writes`.

I can telnet to the mongo hosts from client machine and I can reach the db with command-line interface and all the mongo hosts seem alive. 
Can you give me an advice on troubleshooting this problem?

Some configuration settings to start with:

```
mongo:SECONDARY> db.isMaster()
{
    "hosts" : [
        "mongo-db01h.myhost.net:27017",
        "mongo-db01e.myhost.net:27017",
        "mongo-db01i.myhost.net:27017"
    ],
    "setName" : "mongo",
    "setVersion" : 24,
    "ismaster" : false,
    "secondary" : true,
    "primary" : "mongo-db01h.myhost.net:27017",
    "me" : "mongo-db01e.myhost.net:27017",
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
    "maxMessageSizeBytes" : 48000000,
    "maxWriteBatchSize" : 1000,
    "localTime" : ISODate("2017-08-23T14:25:40.598Z"),
    "maxWireVersion" : 4,
    "minWireVersion" : 0,
    "ok" : 1
}
mongo:SECONDARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "mongo",
    "version" : 24,
    "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "host" : "mongo-db-backup01h.myhost.net:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : true,
            "priority" : 0,
            "tags" : {    

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : 6,
            "host" : "mongo-db01h.myhost.net:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {    

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 8,
            "host" : "mongo-db-backup02h.myhost.net:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : true,
            "priority" : 0,
            "tags" : {    

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : 9,
            "host" : "mongo-db01e.myhost.net:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {    

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 10,
            "host" : "mongo-db01i.myhost.net:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {    

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        }
    ],
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : true,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
        "getLastErrorModes" : {    

        },
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened after the `ServerSelectionTimeoutError` ? Does it automatically fixes itself or do you have to perform some operations to rectify the problem ?

Comment: Sometimes it just fixes itself, but most of the times I have to restart my flask app – and it connects without problems.

Comment: You need to find out how gunicorn connects to your MongoDB server. It sounds like there was [ReplicaSet election](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/) which causes one of the cursor stale. You could check `mongod` log and confirm